# Errors deploying Rails app in shared server with Mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am trying to deploy ror on shared hosting with mysql as database n i m getting this error

```
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Sun Jul 29 09:54:01 +0530 2012
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  no such file to load -- sqlite3
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in `require_library_or_gem'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in `require_library_or_gem'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:10:in `sqlite3_connection'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:99:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/cgi_process.rb:44:in `dispatch_cgi'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:101:in `dispatch_cgi'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:27:in `dispatch'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:76:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `synchronize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:74:in `process'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:282:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `each'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:281:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:128:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in `run'
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
    /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19:in `load'
    /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:19
```

Answer (score 1):

in your Gemfile you should put sqlite in a development group and add mysql gem to the production group. Also your database.yml should have configurations for your mysql server.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

Also don't forget to run `bundle install`. And you also should have the same database in both environments, so you don't have surprises when later be surprised with some erros.

Comment: I don't really see the value of using a production group. Gems will be installed in development as well unless you specify explicitly to bundle without when running bundle install. But heroku is using it in his docs as well. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler

Comment: if i don't have an ssh access what i should do ?? for bundle install